# Неотображаемый сайт с помощью OpenServer

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, браузер, openserver, настройки

Есть папка с сайтами (в Openserver директории - domains)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть также папка с разрабатываемым сайтом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запустил OpenServer (иконка с зеленым флажком справа на Панели Задач). Пытался открыть страницу webovio, webovio.ru (вводил в адресную строку браузера - `webovio`, `localhost/webovio`, `localhost/webovio.ru`, `webovio.ru`) и в результате получал следующий сообщения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отобразить с помощью OpenServer сайт из папки `C:/OpenServer/domains/webovio.ru/index.html`?Должно получиться как на скриншоте снизу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

@АлексейШиманский вводил адрес `http://webovio/index.html` в адресную строку браузера и получил следующие сообщения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

- Адрес в url должен быть таким же, как и называется папка. Один в один.
- Если папка находится в domains, а не в localhost, то и преписка `localhost` не нужна.
- Если в инете существует подобный сайт, то тогда надо пробовать написать с префиксом протокола, т.е.

  ```
  http://НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ
  ```

  тогда появится подсказка в браузере, запускать ли это локально
- Возможно имеет смысл в конце указать `/index.html` Если сам html не подхватывается автоматически

---

часто, чтобы не путаться с боевыми сайтами разработчики ставят либо `dev` либо `local` как префикс или постфикс.... Например у меня сайты типа такого:

```
rkn.local
supergame.local
cryptobank.local
```

Comment: я обновил вопрос - проблема не решилась.

Comment: Ты запускаешь как `test`, хотя папка у тебя `test.ru` . Конечно не решилась, ты не выполнил пункт 1 из ответа))  Также попробуй другой браузер на всякий